# C# Regex; Double Quote Issue

Tags: c#, regex, double-quotes

I'm a little stumped here.  I had this method, which was working fine until just recently:

```
internal static bool IsZplFormat(string szString)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"\^XA.*\^XZ\\r\\n");
    return regex.IsMatch(szString);
}
```

That would work fine given the following string (taken from my unit test):

```
const string zplSample = "^XA blah blah blah ^XZ\r\n";
```

What appears to be happening now, is that I'm getting something like this:

```
const string zplSample = "^XA blah blah \"blah ^XZ\r\n";
```

And now my regex doesn't match anymore.

I thought the `.*` should match all characters, but it seems to be getting tripped up on that double quote.  Any ideas on how I can get this working again?

Comment: so is the input that fails `@"^XA blah blah \""blah ^XZ\r\n"` ?

Comment: I think that's part of my confusion here.  The string I posted is what I'm getting back when I get into the debugger and "Copy Value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing here...

```
string zplSample  = "^XA blah blah blah ^XZ\r\n";
string zplSample1 = "^XA blah blah \"blah ^XZ\r\n";

Console.WriteLine(new Regex(@"\^XA.*\^XZ\r\n").IsMatch(zplSample));
Console.WriteLine(new Regex(@"\^XA.*\^XZ\r\n").IsMatch(zplSample1));

Console.ReadKey();
```

Output

```
True
True
```

What did I change? The regex pattern to `@"\^XA.*\^XZ\r\n"`. (From two `backslashes` to one) (`\\r\\n`)

Comment: OK; it might just be me losing it after a long day, but I don't see any difference between the two regexes there

Comment: OK; I am losing it.  Disregard the prior comment